# Access 2013 only show specific menu item

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I've created a database that starts up with one form opened, from there users can access all the forms and rapports they need.

To make things as simple as possible I've removed all unneeded navigation and menu's, including the ribbon. 
But because the database is moved around a lot I need the users to have access to the Linked Table Manager, just this one menu item.

So my question is if there is way to just show this menu item and hide all the others?
Or if this is not possible if I can link this item to a button an a form?

Comment: You can do a lot with XML ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7907255/hide-access-options/11227830#11227830 ) but I prefer a start up form to find the back-end Db and link a list of tables ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4242063/refreshing-linked-tables-in-access/4244586#4244586 )

Comment: Instead of exposing the Linked Table Manager, you could use something like Armen Stein's relinker utility here: http://www.jstreettech.com/downloads.aspx. It's the J Street Access Relinker (and it's free).