# In access 2007, when you split the database into two files, can you tell it to look in the frontend directory for the backend file?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I'm playing around with splitting access databases. It appears that each table contains a hard link to the backend file in the linked table manager.

But if I wanted to send the file pair to someone through email to look at, the hard links will break. Right now we're at separate offices just testing changes to the program. This isn't in production. I don't want them to get into the development mode and edit the linked table manager because it would be too hard.

Is there a way to tell access to simply look in the front end file's directory for the backend file? Is there a way to force a prompt on the front end to let them choose the location of the backend file?

Thanks!

Comment: Consider something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4242063/refreshing-linked-tables-in-access/4244586#4244586

Comment: You should put this in answer form somehow and I'll upvote it

Comment: I can also just convert it back to one file for him to look at.

Comment: It is not considered proper in StackOverflow to post links, and simply posting my own code seems like self-promotion, so work away, I hope I have helped.

Comment: Been there, done that for you it seems. No problem! Thanks for your assistance

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution is to on startup check if the table link(s) point to the current directory, and if not, then you run re-link code. That way the pair of files will work if you move the pair to a different folder or re-name the folder.
The above is a common setup and EVEN recommend for single user applications that SHOULD be split and benefit by being split.

So on startup, check the path of a linked table. I use the following code to return the path of currently linked tables.

```
Function strBackEndPath() As String

   ' returns the path name to the back end
   ' and includes tralinig \

   Dim mytables As TableDef

   Dim strTempBack As String
   Dim strFullPath As String
   strFullPath = ""

   For Each mytables In CurrentDb.TableDefs
      If Left(mytables.Connect, 10) = ";DATABASE=" Then
         strFullPath = Mid(mytables.Connect, 11)
         Exit For
      End If
    Next mytables

    strBackEndPath = Left(strFullPath, InStrRev(strFullPath, "\"))

End Function
```

With above, then on startup I can go:

```
If CurrentProject.path & "\" <> strBackEndPath Then

   ' call re-link code

End If
```

And there are TONS of re-link code examples floating around but here is a link to some re-linking code.

http://access.mvps.org/access/tables/tbl0009.htm

Thus if the links don’t point to the back end database in the same folder, then re-linking will ONLY occur once and after that only the above “test” to ensure that front end and back end are are linked.
If the folder is renamed or as noted a user moves the files to a different location then again the re-link will occur.

Comment: looks helpful, i'll test it when the time comes. This project runs in fits and starts whenever they get time for me.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the front-end tables and select Linked Table Manager. From there, you can browse for the location of the back-end tables

Comment: sorry, i didn't stipulate that the second user isn't too good with computers.I don't want them going anywhere near the linked table manager. See edited question

Comment: In general, you shouldn't be giving them access to the back-end at all then. E-mail them only the front-end and have only one back-end database.

Comment: can't, because there's no backend file at their office.i have no access to their filesystems.

Comment: It is common and reasonable to place the front end and back end in the same folder. You might have many users all over the place that use the application, but have their own data and the application is NOT multi-user. However the problem then becomes what occurs if the folder name is different, renamed or as noted they move both files to some other location on their computer. And you still need the application split to issue updates and bugs fixes. This is a common setup for most access developers and a common problem that Access developers have to solve.